# Accidentally added a bunch of junk files to Ubuntu One, how can I clean it up?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one, sync, ubuntu-one-windows

I have Ubuntu one set to sync between three computers - a laptop (main one), a desktop with Ubuntu, and the same desktop with windows. I (accidentally) set up u1 to sync the windows documents folder to every other computer, which added a gigabyte of FREAKING USELESS JUNK on to every computer and the cloud.

I went on the laptop to the website and deleted the windows crap, and to make sure that it wouldn't sync, I got rid of it under devices. But whenever I log in, I always get an Ubuntu One Notify-OSD alert saying "'whatever_file.meh'" and 1658 others are Being uploaded to your personal cloud.

How do I fix this? without removing all of my Ubuntu one accounts preferably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the files finally were removed. I don't know why they didn't before, but they are gone now. Might have been a delay from when the files were deleted and when the computer realized they were deleted. Unsure if thats why, but just happy to have the files removed

Answer (score 1):

Go to Ubuntu One website and remove here the folder:

https://one.ubuntu.com/files/

This should delete these files definitely.